# Cant run Sphinx search service on windows

Tags: sphinx

I tried installing Sphinx as a service on windows, and followed the steps mentioned in the following tutorial:
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=2972
But the service doesn't start and gives Error #1067
So, as mentioned in the tutorial, I run `searchd` from console, and this is what I get.
Can someone guide me what am I doing wrong?

```
c:\sphinx\bin>searchd --console
Sphinx 2.0.7-release (r3759)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file './sphinx.conf'...
WARNING: compat_sphinxql_magics=1 is deprecated; please update your application
and config
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
listening on all interfaces, port=9306
precaching index 'test1'
precached 1 indexes in 0.004 sec
binlog: replaying log C:/sphinx/data/binlog.001
binlog: replay stats: 0 rows in 0 commits; 0 updates; 0 indexes
binlog: finished replaying C:/sphinx/data/binlog.001; 0.0 MB in 0.000 sec
binlog: replaying log C:/sphinx/data/binlog.001
binlog: replay stats: 0 rows in 0 commits; 0 updates; 0 indexes
binlog: finished replaying C:/sphinx/data/binlog.001; 0.0 MB in 0.000 sec
binlog: finished replaying total 2 in 0.003 sec
accepting connections
```

Answer (score 1):

What working for me

1. Ensure that folders log and data exist in @confdir@
2. Use full path to config file, not relative

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a complete answer because I have got the same "problem". However, I can probably give you a hint.

Basically, you have already started the daemon which is good news. When you run `searchd` from console and get the message `accepting connections` you can start asking questions! `searchd` is ready to answer (as long as it runs in a console window). I personally ask questions from VB.NET using `Sphinx.Client`. `searchd` listens on ports 9306 and 9312 (you can change it in a config), so I send him questions on port 9312. He answers and I process those answers. That's all.

When I finish searching and close my app, the console is still on and I have to close it manually (Ctrl+Break). And that is what annoys me a little bit. I would imagine that it runs somewhere in the background without me even notice it (service).

Until now I could not figure out why my Sphinx didn't run as a service. Now I have got it working. The problem was that I blindly used a command from Sphinx on-line manual and didn't change **path to config** accordingly. 
Originally (the manual): `C:\Sphinx\bin\searchd --install --config C:\Sphinx\sphinx.conf.in --servicename SphinxSearch`

Working for me: `C:\Sphinx\bin\searchd --install --config C:\Sphinx\sphinx.conf --servicename SphinxSearch`

Correct is `sphinx.conf` and not `sphinx.conf.in` (in my case).

Note: If you have already tried to install `searchd` as a service you might want to delete it first as you can't add another service with the same name. Have a look at e.g. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-windows-service-in-vista-or-xp/. Then issue correct command with correct path to your config. You get desired behaviour, i.e. service runs in the background and will not remain in opened console window.